# How do I make a PL/SQL script output in two different ways depending on user input?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on a PL/SQL script that will take a user decision to either display the results in the SQL Plus window, or export it to a .CSV file based on a user input:

```
ACCEPT output_location PROMPT 'Output: (S) -SQL Output to Screen  (E) - Export to .CSV:  '

!touch /my_path/My_output_file.csv

DECLARE
    (list of variables);
    CURSOR my_cursor IS ...;

BEGIN
    IF '&output_location' = 'E' THEN

        SPOOL $PWD/My_Output_File

        OPEN my_cursor;
        FETCH my_cursor into...;
        WHILE (my_cursor%FOUND) LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my output data);
            FETCH my_cursor into...;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE my_cursor;

        SPOOL OFF

        !cp $PWD/My_output_file.lst $PWD/My_output_file.csv
        set define ">"
        !/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
        set define "&"
    ELSE IF '&output_location' = 'S' THEN
        (Code to output cursor info as a normal SQL execution)
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Everything between `OPEN my_cursor` and `CLOSE my_cursor` works if I move all of the spool and file opening commands outside of the `BEGIN-END` block. As it currently is, it gives me the error:

> PLS-00181: unsupported preprocessor directive '$PWD'

I can move these commands and just have two distinct scripts for a user to run, but I would really prefer to have it all in a one stop shop. How do I split this one script into two different output modes?

Comment: Sorry, but PL/SQL does not support OS calls. There are workarounds, but nothing like what you are trying here.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction of one of the workarounds?

Comment: I could, but WHY? Why not use the "right" approach, which is to control execution flow from the shell script, not from within PL/SQL?

Comment: That's what I meant. Can you point me in the direction of how to do it correctly? Currently I don't know how to accomplish this at all. I'm not familiar with what you are talking about when you say "control execution flow from the shell script", and I don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of missmatch. You're mixing PL/SQL with `bash` commands.

```
!cp $PWD/My_output_file.lst $PWD/My_output_file.csv
        set define ">"
        !/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
        set define "&"
```

This is not valid PL/SQL and it won't work here. You have to either split your scripts or instead of using `bash` use `utl_file` package for creating and handling files.

Comment: `utl_file` will work for limited file operations, but the OP is also trying to run a program, `soffice.bin`. `utl_file` can't handle such calls.

Comment: You're right. I havn't noticed that this is program not other file. One can create executable program in Oracle but it seams complication for me. But maybe create_program from https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm may help

Comment: The short answer is that the conditional execution path should be implemented in the script (enveloping the PL/SQL code), not in the PL/SQL code itself.